# Is SQLite is suitable for personal database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I've done some reading about SQLite. Can someone confirm if it is suitable for personal database which require a lot of calculation, analsis and graph? Currently I am working on Excel on 63 files sizing of 1.34GB. I will be creating a million row and maybe 45+ column depend on which table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people report that SQLite works well for databases sized up to several GB. For better performance, you should care of

- avoiding concurrent updates (probably not an issue for a personal DB)
- creating relevant indices (they are essential if you are going to do a lot of analysis, running joins)
- running multiple inserts in a single transaction (if you need to insert a lot)

45 columns and 63 tables are well within [SQLite limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds entirely practical, but you may wish to consider what the best way of representing the data is. In general, a database works best when each table represents exactly one simple relation, whereas it's all too easy with Excel to jumble everything together.